# How can i make this MySQL query work?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table called 'bandsplusrating' and a table called 'ratings'
The table 'bandsplusrating' is filled with bands, the table 'ratings' starts empty.

Both tables have field called 'naam' with which they can be joined.
Table 'ratings' has a field called 'fullname'

Multiple Ratings per band (bandsplusrating) will be stored in table 'ratings'

Now i want to display all records from 'bandsplusrating' which havent been rated by a given user (ratings.fullname)

```
SELECT b.naam, b.stijl
FROM bandsplusrating b
LEFT JOIN ratings r ON b.naam = r.naam
WHERE r.fullname NOT LIKE 'Obama'
```

This query will still display a record when an other user has rated it.

Im am struggeling for days now, can someone assist me ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using NOT IN:

---

```
SELECT b.naam,
       b.stigl
  FROM BANDPLUSRATING b
 WHERE b.naam NOT IN (SELECT r.naam
                        FROM RATINGS r
                       WHERE r.fullname LIKE 'Obama')
```

### Using NOT EXISTS:

---

```
SELECT b.naam,
       b.stigl
  FROM BANDPLUSRATING b
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM RATINGS r
                   WHERE r.naam = b.naam
                     AND r.fullname LIKE 'Obama')
```

### Using LEFT JOIN/IS NULL:

---

```
   SELECT b.naam,
          b.stigl
     FROM BANDPLUSRATING b
LEFT JOIN RATINGS r ON r.naam = b.naam
                   AND r.fullname LIKE 'Obama'
    WHERE r.naam IS NULL
```

### Performance

---

[Of the three options, the `NOT IN` and `LEFT JOIN/IS NULL` perform equally](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/).  `NOT EXISTS` doesn't perform as well.

Comment: Nice summary of different methods. I'm adding a final extra one to my answer. RE performance: That's probably because the NOT EXISTS solution relies on a correlated subquery.

Comment: @Roland Bouman: All three produce different plans, but the EXISTS is 30% less efficient than the others - see the link.

Comment: Rolands solutions worked, but i couldnt read the result properly(see comment above).
Im using your 'Not' solution now and im testing it as i type, because my query is more complex than the one i posted here.

Thanks for the help. This is my first question here and im very satisfied!!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT    b.naam, b.stijl
FROM      bandsplusrating b
LEFT JOIN ratings r 
ON        b.naam  = r.naam
AND       'Obama' = r.fullname
WHERE     r.naam IS NULL
```

The trick is, the LEFT JOIN is evaluated before the WHERE. So by first letting the join roll out, any rows from bandplusrating that do not match anything in ratings will yield a NULL-record for ratings (a ratings record with only NULL values). Then, you can filter on that using the `WHERE` and by demanding that some known mandatory column from ratings `IS NULL`, you're effectively saying: only those that didn't match.

EDIT:

I just saw OMG Ponies' thorough reply, and decided to add yet another method to do it, which is just a slight variation of the `LEFT JOIN` solution:

```
SELECT    b.naam, b.stijl
FROM      bandsplusrating b
LEFT JOIN ratings r 
ON        b.naam  = r.naam
AND       'Obama' = r.fullname
GROUP BY  b.naam, b.stijl
HAVING    COUNT(r.naam) = 0
```

(Personally I think this one is less good that the prior one)

Comment: Thanks for the QUICK reply. I have to sleep now, will try it tomorrow in an expanded version and will get back. I did a quick run and it looks promising !

Comment: @roland
The result of this query produces duplicate fields (naam, stijl etc.)
I cannot read $row['naam'] therefore.

Comment: Checkerforth, show me some data that demonstrates it. So, some rows from bandplusrating, ratings, and the result with the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739557/sql-query-on-two-tables-return-rows-in-one-table-that-dont-have-entries-in-the) may help you a bit (has some additional explanation that will clarify Roland's answer further).